# Is it possible to hide the colors of tiles in chartview

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

Am using danielgindi charts library and i want to hide the tiles at the corner of chart view image attached below

I tried and managed t[image]o hide the strings  by setting empty string but couldn't find option to hide the tile
chart created using following code

```
 func setChartNew() {
        //barChartViewShow is uiview with barchartview as file's owner which means in storyboard changed class to barchartview
        barChartViewShow.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."
        
        var dataEntries4: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
              
           for i in 0..<self.cashArray.count  {
               print(Double(self.cashArray[i]) ?? 0.0)
 
               let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i) , y: Double(self.cashArray[i]) ?? 0.0)
               dataEntries.append(dataEntry)

               let dataEntry1 = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i) , y: Double(self.cardArray[i]) ?? 0.0)
               dataEntries1.append(dataEntry1)

               let dataEntry2 = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i) , y:  Double(self.applePayArray[i]) ?? 0.0)
               dataEntries2.append(dataEntry2)
               let dataEntry3 = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i) , y:  Double(self.googlePayArray[i]) ?? 0.0)
               dataEntries3.append(dataEntry3)
           }
 //here i have hidden the texts applepay,googlepay,cash,card //
         chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "")
         chartDataSet1 = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries1, label: "")
         chartDataSet2 = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries2, label: "")
         chartDataSet3 = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries3, label: "")
  //here i have hidden the texts applepay,googlepay,cash,card //
        /*values above bar disabled*/
        chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
        chartDataSet1.drawValuesEnabled = false
        chartDataSet2.drawValuesEnabled = false
        chartDataSet3.drawValuesEnabled = false
          /*values above bar disabled*/
/*set colors for bars and assign to dataset to display bars*/
           let dataSets: [BarChartDataSet] = [chartDataSet,chartDataSet1,chartDataSet2,chartDataSet3]

chartDataSet2.colors = [UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 192/255, blue: 112/255, alpha: 1)] // 1, 192, 112 applePay
 chartDataSet3.colors = [UIColor(red: 75/255, green: 192/255, blue: 192/255, alpha: 1)] //75, 192, 192 googlePay
        chartDataSet1.colors = [UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 164/255, blue: 26/255, alpha: 1)]  //249, 164, 26 card
        chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 96/255, blue: 44/255, alpha: 1)] //241, 96, 44 cash
        chartDataSet.highlightColor = .black

            let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
         let groupSpace = 0.200
        let barSpace = 0.06
        let barWidth = 0.142
             let groupCount = self.days.count
            let axisMinimum = 0

            chartData.barWidth = barWidth;
        barChartViewShow.xAxis.axisMinimum = Double(startYear)
            let gg = chartData.groupWidth(groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)
            
        barChartViewShow.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(axisMinimum) + gg * Double(groupCount)

            chartData.groupBars(fromX: Double(axisMinimum), groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)
         barChartViewShow.notifyDataSetChanged()

        barChartViewShow.data = chartData
 
        barChartViewShow.backgroundColor = UIColor .white

            //chart animation
        barChartViewShow.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.5, yAxisDuration: 1.5, easingOption: .easeOutSine)
       
        }
```

where label was string value But i couldn't hide the tile images above[image]
Kindly guide me to hide the tiles inside chart

the library i have followed and used is in below link

> https://cocoapods.org/pods/Charts

Comment: Do you mean the legend? Please can you link the framework you are using.

Comment: https://cocoapods.org/pods/Charts i have used charts framework

Comment: Please can you clarify which bit you want to remove?

Comment: the tiles inside graph near bars above

Comment: That is called the `legend`. Looking at the library, every chart has a `legendRenderer`. I'd take a look to see if there are any customisation options there to hide the legend.

Comment: ok i will try using keyword kindly update if you get any ideas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237885/discussion-between-gopinath-and-fogmeister).

Comment: Can you add the code you have now for adding the bar chart so we could recreate this?

Comment: updated the question by adding  the code which chart has been displayed kindly check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `disable` the legend as below in `setChartNew()`. Once you `disable` the legend, it won't be shown in the chart anymore.

```
let legend = barChartViewShow.legend
legend.enabled = false
```

[image]